# Getting all possible cities. MSQL (ORIGIN - DESTINATION)

Tags: mysql, database

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has this kind of problem.

I need to get the all the cities next to **200**. Below is my sample table.

```
ID | MID | CID | OrderNum
59 | 100 | 200 | 1
60 | 101 | 200 | 1
61 | 102 | 200 | 1
62 | 100 | 201 | 2
63 | 100 | 202 | 3
64 | 101 | 202 | 2
65 | 102 | 203 | 5
66 | 105 | 201 | 2
```

This is the only result I need to get.

```
ID | MID | CID | OrderNum
62 | 100 | 201 | 2
64 | 101 | 202 | 2
65 | 102 | 203 | 5
```

NOTE:

ID #63 and #66 mustn't return as #63 is in the third order and #66 is in another MID.

The ID #65 should be returned because there are no OrderNumber 2,3 and 4 in MID #102.

I'm sure this is possible but I am running out of ideas on How To.

Please help, I'm currently searching for workarounds

Comment: What means `next to 200`?

Comment: I mean CID next to 200.. as you can see each MIDs have CIDs and Order Number, I need to get all CID which is next to 200.. Please help. Apologize for my bad english.

Comment: I've tried getting all ORDER NUMBER greater than 1 and after that I call another query to check if it is followed by CID #200 (this solution works) BUT it takes minutes to display the results. Right now I'm looking for better and faster solution.

Comment: Show your sql statement please.

Comment: First I have this query

SELECT * FROM table WHERE OrderNum > 1

then after I get all rows, I do this query next 

Select CID 
FROM table 
WHERE MID = XXX 
AND OrderNum < XXX 
ORDER BY OrderNum DESC
LIMIT 1

when I get the CID

I'll check now if the CID I get is equal to 200

Doing this solution works, but very slow. If only I can get the next data in my first query maybe it will run faster.

Comment: Oh no. Im sorry. I thought new line works in comments :(